Using quarto in Windows
Am still stuck with Rmarkdown because I am still unale to run quarto on my Windows machine. Is there a way to deal with this issue?
ERROR: Error executing 'reg': Access is denied. (os error 5)

This issue has been discussed here https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/8245.
Probably you need to install Quarto with the version of 1.4.543 or newer.

This answers my question! It has taken me a while to get here!!!
